# declared font weight but can't call font weight

Tags: html, css, font-face

I added a font & declared font weight:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
font-weight: 700; 
src: url("fonts/Gotham-Medium-Regular.woff");
}
```

But font-weight doesn't work - so the below code doesn't call the Medium font (it calls the bold font). What am I doing wrong?  Btw I didn't have to add regular & bold gotham font files, somehow I already had access to it.

```
.active, .accordion:hover {
font-weight: 700;
}
```

Below code correctly calls medium font, but I'm hoping to use 'font-weight' to call the medium font.

```
.active, .accordion:hover {
 font-family: 'Gotham-Medium'; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a font weight to call a font. You need to use both together if you're using a font-face.

```
.active, .accordion:hover {
     font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
     font-weight: 700;
 }
```

Edit: are both fonts in separate files? if so, you should be able to use them like this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    font-weight: 400; 
    src: url("fonts/Gotham-Medium-Regular.woff");
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    font-weight: 700; 
    src: url("fonts/Gotham-Bold-Regular.woff");
}

.active, .accordion {
    font-family: 'Gotham'
    font-weight: 400;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I have a very strange problem where it's a Medium font on hover and a Bold font on active.....  is there any chance you know what's wrong here? code here: 
  active, .accordion:hover {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
  font-weight: 700;
  }

Comment: What would you like to happen? medium then bold on hover?

Comment: medium for both hover & active

Comment: Put the font weight that you want on the accordion class. Then the font weight that you want on the .active and .accordion:hover

Comment: I think that was my original code ----> .active, .accordion:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
} <-----     it applies Medium to hover and Bold to active.....  really not sure what i'm doing wrong here.